# Laravel query where col1 != col2

Tags: laravel, orm

I have DB with table 'items' with columns 'col1', 'col2' and other.
I need result items by laravel ORM.
Condition: all items where col1 != col2

```
where col1 != col2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Laravel `whereColumn`. It is use to compare two column. You can check doc here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries

```
DB::table('table_name')->whereColumn('col1', '<>', 'col2')->get();
```